# android activity work with intent

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent, android-activity

i made three activities for a game i want to go from 1st to 2nd to 3rd and then go 1st 2nd 3rd again but i got confused with the whole intent thing tried all kind of combinations but for some reason i stuck always with a problem currently it goes from 1st to 2nd to 3rd to 1st and when it supposed to lunch 2nd it exits from the whole app

```
//1st activity
    Intent discoverintent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), discoverstring.class);
    //discoverintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(discoverintent);

//2nd activity
    Intent MainIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), learningword.class);
    //MainIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    MainIntent.putExtra("text", text);
    MainIntent.putExtra("speakeronoff", Integer.toString(speakeronoff));
    MainIntent.putExtra("previous", Integer.toString(previous));

    startActivity(MainIntent);
```

and the 3rd activity just uses finish

```
package self.yanfaingold.talkgame;







import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;







@SuppressLint("NewApi") public class savewords extends Activity implements OnTouchListener  {
OurView v;
//Intent secondintent;
Canvas c;


int cheight,cwidth,loop=0;
Bitmap notalk,notalkscaled,bittalk;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        v=new OurView(this);
        v.setOnTouchListener(this);



        //Remove title bar
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        //Remove notification bar
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(v);

        notalk=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.nottalk);
       // bittalk=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.talkmid);

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        v.pause();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();
        v.resume();
    }


    public class OurView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

        Thread t=null;
        SurfaceHolder holder;
        boolean isItOK=false;

        public OurView(Context context) {
            super(context);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            holder=getHolder();


        }
        public void run(){

            while(isItOK){
                if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
                    continue;
                }
                c=holder.lockCanvas();
                cheight=c.getHeight();
                cwidth=c.getWidth();

                scale();


                drawing(c);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
            }
        }
        private void scale() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(loop==0)
                notalkscaled=Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(notalk,(int)(cwidth),(int)(cheight), false);


        }
        protected void drawing(Canvas canvas){
            //canvas.drawARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            canvas.drawBitmap(notalkscaled,0,0, null);
            if(loop>500){
                loop=0;
            wannalearnaword();

            }
            loop++;
        }
        private void wannalearnaword() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //1st activity
            Intent secondintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), discoverstring.class);
            secondintent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(secondintent);
        }
        public void pause(){
            isItOK=false;
            while(true){
                try {
                    t.join();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            }
            t=null;
        }
        public void resume(){
            isItOK=true;
            t=new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }
        }













    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch(event.getAction())
        {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:


            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

            break;
        }
        return true;
    }




}
```

Comment: Please post the intent code in each of the activities and what does each activity does when it starts.

Comment: it is the intent code about what they do is 1st activity sends to 2nd activity after couple of seconds cause i didnt worked on it yet 2nd and 3rd activity use ontouchlistener and i made a game in both of this activitys using bitmaps its a whole bunch of code and its not connected to the intent part basicly each activity got a holder of canvas that i draw on and i use a thread to draw cause a guide said that view is already do things and better create your own view

Comment: What is your logcat output?

Comment: How does the third activity go to the first activity directly after it calls finish()?

Comment: Post the code of the first activity.

Comment: from what i am reading i think, android was tired with your activites, and it closed it..lol..

Comment: haha im am tired with my activities as well all day tried to fix this apperntly it works now when i told my 3rd activity to go to 1sy activity and created aloop of some sort but im not sure cause 1 check is not enogth if it works and about it makes no sense exctly why i suffer all this day

Comment: posted 1st activity code hehe

Comment: logcat as i remember 72 warnings 0 errors

Comment: I don't see any code where you're calling an intent.

Comment: inside the drawing function i call to wannalearnaword function which sends the intent startActivity(secondintent);